# Why is my question gone?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

It wasn't a stellar question, but it was the only one I have ever posted here. If I remember right, the question itself didn't get any upvotes, but the answer I posted a few days later, did. It concerned Jeff Dunham. Since a comment made me chuckle, I have looked at it several times. At least several weeks after posting the question and the eventual answer, I saw no close votes or possible dupes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/34166/49) was closed by the community on May 28th for not sufficing the site's quality standards for ID questions. Then it was deleted on June 9th for being closed more than 9 days without improvement.

Comment: But the 9-day [roomba deletion](http://movies.stackexchange.com/help/roomba) doesn't delete questions that have positively scored answers. Is Jolene mistaken about the answer getting upvotes?

Comment: @randal'thor No, roomba doesn't grip if there is an upvoted answer. But this doesn't stop moderators from performing manual cleanup. (She did however, not lose any reputation from the deletion, since her answer had +3 and was older than 60 days.)